# What workflow to use with Gerrit if two people are collaborating narrowly?

Tags: git, workflow, gerrit

Our client is using Gerrit without feature branches, and so far they've usually had fairly large changesets for new stories. Our company is new at the codebase, so we're tackling the user stories in pairs and parcelling out the work.

Gerrit seems to have woefully little documentation that addresses a scenario other than 1 committer : 1 reviewer. Were it not for Gerrit and its insistence on sharing changes through repeatedly rewritten public history, the answer would be "share a feature branch and squash merge it later" What would be the workflow for, say, the following:

- Anne and Barney are working together on a form that edits a list of widgets.
- To split up the cognitive load of working on a large preexisting codebase, Anne will focus on the "backend" - correctly adding / removing / replacing widgets in the domain model; and Barney will work on the "frontend" - design the form and write the UI code.
- The design is that Anne will expose an IWidgetService for Barney to use. Now, this serves only to have a nice explicit boundary between the UI and the business logic - this is not an API that can be frozen, much less implemented up front.
- This means that it's going to be a regular occurrence that Barney will need to change IWidgetService a bit, but only code against the interface, and leave it up to Anne to realize the change because she knows that part of the code better.

(Names changed to protect the innocent.)

What exactly should Anne and Barney be doing in this case to be able to sync up their work, while also not bypassing the review-based process entirely and just setting up a remote to one another's computer? Preferrably while using Git as idiomatically as possible, because Barney is completely new to Git, and while Anne knows how to do a bit of Git surgery she'd rather not. (E.g. bad = make a "backend" changeset and a "frontend" changeset based on it and when either gets updated do some voodoo to rebase things correctly.)

Comment: I find myself having similar questions. Have you figured out a co-authored feature workflow in Gerrit since asking this?

Comment: @redhotvengeance - for now I went with "Git surgery." What we do is that at any given time, a person "owns" a changeset. I checks in some sort of skeleton that my coworker can code against for the time being, we both continue independently, and sync up now and then. What that means is my coworker knows I'll be rewriting history, I paste commits together by cherry-picking the latest versions from Gerrit on top of one another, then submitting for review and we continue. We also keep changesets small, and then squash them together now and then before they're mergeable.

Comment: @redhotvengeance - this means that at any given time we can amend the changeset we own without affecting anyone else's changes, which is really the pain point. The Git surgery is pretty annoying but practically less error-prone and time-consuming than I expected it to be. And making changesets small until merged makes rebasing onto master easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things blow-up when you try to enforce new-age change-management workflow on a legacy system.

- "fairly large changesets" is bad
- Dividing the work to "backend" and "frontend" WITHOUT some sort of API is... bad
- Users should have some knowledge of git

To resolve -

- Concentrate on doing **small changes**
- Make sure the changes **don't break** the system
  (each change should pass proper automated-verification)
- Try to organize the **work** in a way that reduces dependency between developers
- Try to organize the **product** in a way that reduces dependency between components
- There are tools to help ease the pain for developers, like **[git-gerrit](https://github.com/fbzhong/git-gerrit)**

**EDIT:**

Regarding **small changes**, please consider the following set of
**[non-breaking changes](http://geek-and-poke.com/2015/9/1/simply-explained)** as an example:

1. **Design the interface**, i.e.:
   How the *frontend* ("FE") sends the request to the *backend* ("BE")
   and how the reply is received back.
2. Gerrit-Change 1: **Implement the interface**
3. Gerrit-Change 2: **Implement a stub for the BE** that will receive the request from the FE
   and return a fictive (but valid) reply
4. Gerrit-Changes 3,4: **Work in parallel** on the BE and FE implementations
   (submit each part as a different change)

Pushing Change-1 and then Change-2 to the branch should not break the product,
and will allow working in parallel on the actual implementation of the feature,
without forcing developers to cherry-pick each-other's work.
Now they could simply `git pull --rebase` the main branch, like normal people do.

Good luck!

Comment: I'n trying, but being fairly new to the project it takes our guys a long time to get a change through review; especially since the codebase likes to break mysteriously (to us) when sneezed at. The "frontend"/"backend" split is mainly so we split the cognitive load of figuring out a large codebase with hardly any documentation and questionable design choices - a "one feature-level story per person" split seemed overwhelming.

Comment: Git/Gerrit is best for agile workflows, and sounds like your "features" are _too big to fit one change_. Especially when the system is breakable, small changes on the master-branch, backed-up by massive automated-testing is the best way to go. This way you can introduce a fix fairly quickly. (I understand you are not there, yet - neither are we)

Comment: It seems like overkill for a project with three internal/contractor developers per module or so - going from "two long-time seniors reviewing one another's output" to "suddenly! newbies" has been awkward. It also seems to me its main benefit - being able to tell what's new in a "changeset" since last time you looked - could've been implemented without losing the advantages and familiarity of append-only shared branches; that is, instead of replacing Git's conceptual model with an incompatible one, figuring out how extract the latter's information from the former. See also: linearizing history.

Comment: Again, it sounds as if the changes are too big and complicated - should really try to break those to _much smaller_ chunks. Regarding "linearizing history", make sure Gerrit _Submit Type_ is set to [Rebase if Necessary] or [Cherry Pick] (this is configured at the Project-level).

Comment: Right, so, e.g.: do an interface class or two in a pair session, then have one person get that change through review, have the other person continue working off of that changeset by making a first draft of the interface implementation; then have person 2 get that merged while the first person does the client code, rinse, repeat. Breaking changes to the API go into a new change after the first cycle is complete to avoid Git surgery as much as possible. In short, keep the lifecycle of a change short rather than making it a "complete" implementation of something.

Comment: Re: the linearizing, that was just an opinionated aside - the client sets this up anyway. I think the whole idea of rebase/amend-based workflows is somewhat ass-backwards; It seems mostly to blame on the lack of tools that would be able to take a Git repo used idiomatically, and then mine that for information a given user wants in his role. (Rather than forcing the developer to work in ways that make the bread-and-butter task of "sharing changes with the team" awkward.) Basically it trades friction in one use case for friction in another use case, which seems like a space for improvement.

Comment: Let's not blame the messenger... git/Gerrit only reflect the status of the project: A tightly-coupled system is very sensitive to modifications, and no-one will risk his neck trying to untangle (refactor) it.